# Cannot import python social auth into Django app that uses custom login

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, django-models, python-social-auth

Using Django 1.6.5, created a custom login framework for username/password token-based logins but now want to implement some social login too. The only problem with this, is that every example in existence is using Django's built-in templates and so forth which are not helpful.

In trying to use `python-social-auth` I've discovered that I don't understand anything about relative imports and despite reading many SOs about it, I'm still confused as to how I should go about referencing my Django app in `/home/django/project` from the pip-installation location of `python-social-auth`: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social`.

Now why would I want to alter any of this code you may be wondering...well it's quite simple really in that I've already created this username/password login system based off of tokens so I'm trying to figure out a way to give social-authed users a token as well. The only way I see that to be possible is by accessing my custom `UserProfile` object from my existing models, while inside the `python-social-auth` code and then slapping a token on users when they login. The file I'd need to alter is `actions.py` which you can see the location of in the diagram below.

I've already tried by using `pip uninstall python-social-auth` and actually just copying the entire folder of social auth code into my project in `/home/django/project`, the references work just fine there and no need to refactor anything...except again I can't import my own models from my Django app since it's 'outside' of the social module. So I guess I have two or three questions.

1. Should I leave (and edit) the `python-social-auth` code in place at
   `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social` (scenario #1) or
   should I just `pip uninstall` it, and copy the social folder into my
   own project for editing it there(scenario #2)?
2. Depending on which scenario I choose, how do I properly import models from my project into the social code? I will outline the directory structure of each
   scenario...generally in my project when I need to import the `UserProfile` object I do: `from apps.app1.models import UserProfile` but that clearly won't work if I try to import it into a file living at `/usr/local/lib...`

**Scenario #1** *(custom `UserProfile` object is inside `app1` models.py)*:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/
    __init__.py
    actions.py
       apps/
          __init__.py
          django_app/
              __init__.py
              default/
                  __init__.py


project/
manage.py
   __init__.py
   apps/
      __init__.py
      app1/
         __init__.py
      app2/
         __init__.py
      app3/
         __init__.py
```

**Scenario #2** *(I copy the entire /social/ folder into `/home/django/project`)*:

```
project/
manage.py
   __init__.py
   apps/
      __init__.py
      app1/
         __init__.py
      app2/
         __init__.py
      app3/
         __init__.py
   social/
       __init__.py
       actions.py
       apps/
          __init__.py
          django_app/
              __init__.py
              default/
                  __init__.py
```

Clearly writing out how to import `UserProfile` from `app1` inside the actions.py file in either scenario is what I'm looking for. Or better way to do what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the pipeline feature in `python-social-auth` to setup that `token`, for example (pseudo code):

```
def set_token(user, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    profile = get_or_create_profile(user)
    profile.token = "new token"
    profile.save()
```

Let's say you put that function in a file at `project/apps/app1/pipeline.py`, then add this entry to your settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
    'apps.app1.pipeline.set_token'
)
```